# Spring MVC with REST integrated with sshd server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, sshd, apache-mina

I'd like to use sshd server (Apache Mina) in my Spring MVC project with REST. To login into webapp I use JavaFX client. When user click "Login",first the client set up ssh connection with private key to sshd server. Then client receives ssl cert (for REST HTTPS) from sshd server. After that there is user authentication with login and password.

Can anyone tell me, how to integrate sshd server with Spring MVC?
How to program this login scenario?

Comment: I'm not really 100% sure what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need a HTTP (note REST isn't a technology but an architectural style) frontent/interface to your SSH server. S/FTP and HTTP both are actually just protocols for managing files on a remote location. Why don't you use `JSch` (S/FTP client implementation) in your client application to talk to your S/FTP server and propagate the authorization request to your JavaFX application?

Comment: REST can use HTTPS so I need on client side a cert to verify server side. I want to set ssh server into spring container as bean. Only way probably is to use sshd. Hmm, if it's impossible better will be to set up ssh server separately ?

Comment: Technically you can of course bridge or map S/FTP commands via HTTP/S operations by accepting HTTP operations on the server side and then converting them to S/FTP commands issued to the S/FTP server, though where is the benefit of doing so compared of directly managing files via HTTP/S or running a dedicated S/FTP server and then using a S/FTP client to interact directly with that server?